# Python SQLite http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/creating-database/

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm creating my first database with python and I'm using SQLite. I'm [following the official tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/creating-database/) but it's giving me the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'conn' referenced before assignment

As far as I understand this means it was call too early but I can't understand why.

Below is my code:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        print(sqlite3.version)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_connection("C:\\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db")
```

Comment: Edit your post with the full stack trace please. Just a preliminary guess but it looks like your "create_connection" function tries to connect with sqlite3.connect(db_file) before the .db file is made, but I can't really tell if there is a different part of your code that creates the .db before this exceprt of code.

Comment: I changed the connection to ```create_connection("pythonsqlite.db")``` and it runs smoothly in my Windows 8 machine.

Comment: @arsho that's because the DB will now be created in whatever directory your CWD happens to be at the time of execution.

Comment: @mpf82, thanks for the clarification. I escape the explanation in comment. For future reader, cwd = current working directory means the directory where the script is kept.

Comment: @arsho The Current Working Directory is normally the directory where the main script is started from, not necessarily the directory where the main script is located. But it's also possible that the CWD is changed with ``os.chdir(path)`` and now points somewhere completely different. Thus it's best to access files with their absolute path, instead of just the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial is just horrible.

Here's what's wrong with it:

1) It only works if the path `C:\sqlite\db\` already exists on your machine.

2) The notation `"C:\\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db"` (even though correct) should be written as `r"C:\sqlite\db\pythonsqlite.db"` (notice the leading **r** that tells Python that this a a raw string) to minimize the chance of a failure due to an escape character (lucky the DB is not called `test.db`, otherwise `C:\\sqlite\db\test.db` would point somewhere "funny", since `\t` will be converted to a TAB).

3) The `finally` part will always be executed. Now, if your path does not exist, you will see the print `unable to open database file` - because the DB can not be created. If the DB can not be created, the connection can not be created. If the connection can not be created `conn` is not defined - but remember we will still execute the `finally` block.

To sum it up:

If the path does not exists, `conn` is not defined but `conn.close()` is still executed, which will result in `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'conn' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks for making it clear and going through each step.